# how to separate touching shapes in a image using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, edge-detection

I'm currently working on image segmentation project and what I want to do after successfully predicting a mask is to quantify the objects in the image like amount, area diameters and etc.

The problem is that I'm failing to separate the objects and I have tried morphological filters and using different contour retrieval methods .

This is one the results of a mask for a SEM image of ductile fracture:

[image]

The internal and external contours :

[image]

[image]

Original image:

[image]

What am I missing? Is there an algorithm or a way to solve this using python?

Comment: Your problem seems ill defined. What exactly are you trying to measure ? Two human observers would detect the "objects" differently.

Comment: As you can see there is a lot of almost circular objects and other different shapes, in the black and white images, and these are boundaries to the dimples in the original image (the boundaries are the the light pixels ) and and I'm trying to detect each individual object and make some measurements about it .

Comment: I don't think you understood my remark. This task is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try dilating & eroding your image, sort of like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (11, 11), 1)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 200, 0)
    kernel = np.ones((7, 7))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=1)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=1)

def get_contours(img):
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if  500 < area < 10000:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), -1) 

get_contours(img)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Where you can access each contour individually in the `for` loop.